# Scan for files in current directory only with ioutils ReadDir when imported through another file

Tags: go

I'm having an issue with ioutils.ReadDir, for some reason it's scanning for all files in the project root instead of in the current directory only.

./main.go

```
import (
    "myfolder/myfile"
)

func main() {
    myfile.MyFunction()
}
```

./myfolder/myfile.go

```
package myfile

func MyFunction() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, f := range files {
        fi, err := os.Stat(f.Name())
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            return
        }

        switch mode := fi.Mode(); {
        case mode.IsDir():
            fmt.Printf("%#s  is a folder\n", f.Name())
        case mode.IsRegular():
            fmt.Printf("%#s is a file\n", f.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not really sure why it is behaving like this, I'm new to Go. My guess is because it's being imported through main.go. How can I make it only search for folders and files in `./myfolder`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current directory is not the directory of the source files, but rather the current directory of whoever executes the program.

If you're executing the program from a shell (be it bash or the Windows command line), the program inherits the current directory from your shell.

You must change the current directory with `cd myfolder` before executing the program or call `os.Chdir("myfolder")` in your Go source file. (`os.Chdir` doesn't affect your shell's current directory)

If you want to list a directory recursively, you must walk it. See [filepath.Walk](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk).

Comment: I'm already running `go run main.go` in the relative folder. I tried `os.Chdir` and it doesn't seem to find all directories and files in the chosen folder, but just on one level.

Comment: @P.Nick What do you mean by one level? Does it list all files in "./myfolder" but not in it's subdirectories?

Comment: If I have `/myfolder/one/two/file.go` it will only print `myfolder/one` even though it has multiple folders and also a file.

Comment: @P.Nick This is expected behavior. Listing a directory isn't a recursive operation. You must walk a directory if you want to list it recursively. See [filepath.Walk](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk)

Comment: Thanks! You've been of much help!

Comment: @P.Nick Glad to have helped ;-)